# How to make selected checkboxes with using array for data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html-select, selected

I have 7 checkbox's for day selection. For example:

```html
<span><input name="days" type="checkbox" value="1" id="day1"><label for="day1">M</label></span>
<span><input name="days" type="checkbox" value="2" id="day2"><label for="day2">T</label></span>
<span><input name="days" type="checkbox" value="3" id="day3"><label for="day3">W</label></span>
<span><input name="days" type="checkbox" value="4" id="day4"><label for="day4">T</label></span>
<span><input name="days" type="checkbox" value="5" id="day5"><label for="day5">F</label></span>
<span><input name="days" type="checkbox" value="6" id="day6"><label for="day6">S</label></span>
<span><input name="days" type="checkbox" value="7" id="day7"><label for="day7">S</label></span>
```

And I also have an array :

```js
var selectedDays = ["5","6"];
```

I want the 5th and 6th days to be selected on load. Any short way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.each(selectedDays, function(i, val) {
    $('#day'+val).prop('checked', true);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$.each(selectedDays,function(i,v){
   $('input:checkbox[value="'+ v +'"]').prop('checked',true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3924B/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedDays = ["5", "6"];
    $('input[name="days"]').each(function () {
        for(i=0;i<selectedDays.length;i++){
            if($(this).attr('value') == selectedDays[i]){
                $(this).prop('checked',true);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Another Js code**

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3924B/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var selectedDays = ["5", "6"];
    $.each(selectedDays, function (i, v) {
        $('input:checkbox[value="' + v + '"]').prop('checked', true);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $(function () {
        var selectedDays = ["5", "6"];
        $.each(selectedDays, function (i, v) {
            $('input:checkbox[value="' + v + '"]').attr('checked', true);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want Friday and Saturday be Checked you can do add

```
checked="checked"
```

to your input

```
<input name="days" type="checkbox" value="5" id="day5" checked="checked">
<input name="days" type="checkbox" value="6" id="day6" checked="checked">
```